# Django abstractuser can't set parameters

Tags: django-forms, abstractuser

I am trying to set a flag when a user signs up. The flags show up on the admin site, so I know the abstract user was implemented.  When I toggle them in the admin area it works as well.  I just can't get the form to work for regular users.  I have tried many combinations with self.instance and self.request.

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    self.instance.user.is_member = True
    ### additional code that works and sets non-abstractuser parameter ####
    return super(UpdateUserProfileForm, self).save(commit=commit)

def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.user = self.request.User
    # form.instance.user.is_member = True
    # self.request.user.is_member = True
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

Answer (score 1):

After further research I needed to add the lines

```
def save(self, commit=True):
    user = self.instance.user
    user.is_member = True
    user.save()
```